# DigitalOcean VPS Tomcat server: can't configure port 80 and multiple domain names

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, vps, java

I have a VPS (droplet) on DigitalOceanI'm trying to configure 80 port and several domain names for my server.

After reading some questions and answers I edited my server.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

      <Host name="codingrecords.tk"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

         <Alias>www.codingrecords.tk</Alias>


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />


       <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/Test"
    debug="0" reloadable="true"/>

      </Host>


    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Namely, I changed the port in `<Connector>` and added an extra `<Host>` block. However now not only can't I access the file by `IP`, `IP:80`, `IP:8080`, I also can't access it using `codingrecords.tk` domain name. The domain name has two A records that point to my droplet's IP address.

Comment: Did you actually _start_ Tomcat with this configuration? What's in catalina.out?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.

First I need to change `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I changed a `User=tomcat` to `User=root`, because otherwise Tomcat automatically used to non-root user and the port bind failed. Not it looks fine!